# Calculate the average of a 2d array over 1 dimension c++

Tags: c++

I have a 2d array [pixels =100][sensors =50] (provided in a data.cpp file)
I need the average of the values given by the sensors for each pixel. The result should be stored in E[100]/50 containing the average values previously calculated.

** Edit: problem solved!! it was in the array type `short` once I changed that I got the right values! Thanks to everyone who took time to answer my query also thanks for introducing me to `containers`**

here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "const.h"
#include "data.h"
#include "SortEngine.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "fonction.h"
//example of how data is defined data 2darray[pixels = 10][sensors = 3]






      /* unsigned short 2darray{{ 10025 , 10192 , 10028 , 10129 , 10199 , 9843 , 9823 , 9857 , 9996 , 9873},
    {10081 , 10122 , 9853 , 10060 , 10027 , 10165 , 10154 , 9853 , 9877, 9816},
    {9845 , 9876 , 9954 , 9836 , 9876 , 10035 , 10094 , 9946 , 10195 

, 10080}} */


    void moyenne(unsigned short average[pixels])
{
    unsigned short transtab[pixels][sensors];
    unsigned short E[pixels];
    unsigned int i,k, count;

    Acquisition(0, transtab);// function to get the data from data.cpp


    for(i=0; i<pixels; i++)
    {
        E[i] = 0;
        average[i] = 0;
        count = 0;

        for(k=0; k<sensors; k++)
        {
            E[i] = E[i] + transtab[i][k];

            count++;
        }
        if(count != 0){
        average[i] = E[i]/count;
        }
        cout << average[i] << endl;

        }

    }
```

I've been stuck on this for literally 2 days as I don't see the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: value expected for average[0] = 10029 while the value I'm getting with my code: 853 (normally, The code should sum all elements of transtab[0][k] (where k<50) where the average is this sum by count)

Comment: What do you expect? Does the code compile?

Comment: Make testing output after each step, and you should find your error(s) easily.

Comment: C++ don't have 2D arrays, only arrays of arrays (which are sometimes named 2D arrays, but they are not). Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: And C++ have powerful standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). You should consider using them.

Comment: Yes the code compile but the values I'm getting are different from the expected values (I did the calculations using Excel to check the average of each column).

Comment: *I've been stuck on this for literally 2 days as I don't see the problem* -- Instead of this code, why not write a very small program that simply takes a 2 dimensional array of known data, and compute the average of each row?  We have no idea what is in your data file.  Second, adding up all of those `short` values in the calculation of the average may overflow `short`.  You really should be doing some debugging and actually print out the value of those sums.  Don't be surprised if the value is some very small value.

Comment: It's a sound approach, I'll write a test code where the 2d array is known to test my code (I didn't notice the problem with the data type!) Thank you !

Comment: In addition, averages are usually floating point values.  For example `7 / 3` is not `2.33...`.  It is `2`, if you are dividing integers.  Your code is all integer, thus expect truncation when computing the average.  Your `average` array will not contain the proper values if you expected fractional results.

Comment: you dont need the `count` as it will be equal to `sensors` always. Also note that there is `std::accumulate` so you do not need to write the inner loop yourself and for the outer loop you could use `std::for_each`

Comment: the purpose of this code is to optimize the use of the CPU (LEON 50MHz) for an embedded system that's why I didn't use floating values and defined all my variables as unsigned short. (to minimize the CPU cycles for each algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are counting the empty array values.
With your code count is always equal to sensors.
You must first check if transtab[i][k] != 0

```
for(k=0; k<sensors; k++)
{
  if (transtab[i][k] != 0) {
    E[i] = E[i] + transtab[i][k];
    count++;
  }
}
```